# attempt at parsing JSON file in Swift 5 ("Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.")

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a stocks app for college related work and ive done almost everything i need to do except getting the actual data of the stocks into my app, I've been trying this and researching for the past couple days but still cannot get it to work as i get the error message :

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

any help is appreciated as this is the first ever thing i've made with swift/xcode

the code in my viewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController { 
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchPostData { (posts) in
            for post in posts {
                print(post.datetime!)
            }
        }                
    }
    
    func fetchPostData(completionHandler: @escaping ([Post]) -> Void) {
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=AAPL&interval=1min&apikey=<api-key>")!
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let postsData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data)
                
                completionHandler(postsData)
                
            }
            catch {
                let error = error
                print(error)
            }                                                        
        }.resume()        
    }        
}
```

and the other file with the variables:

```
struct Post: Codable {
    var datetime: Int!
    var open: Int!
    var high: String!
    var low: String!
    var close: String!
    var volume: String!
}
```

link to the json file: https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=AAPL&interval=1min&apikey=0561a81a9baf4ae4bc65c7af9196f929

Comment: You need to decode the complete json message, you can’t start in the middle. To get a good idea how to form your struct’s for decoding use https://quicktype.io/

Comment: Unrelated but never never ever declare struct members as implicit unwrapped optionals (`!`). If you want optionals declare regular optionals (`?`) otherwise the code compiles even without the exclamation marks.

Comment: It's missing the top level: `meta` & `values` keys before having really `Post`...

Comment: Tip: `let reversed = [Post(datatime: 3, open: 2, ...), Post(datatime:...)]; let encoded = try! JSONEncoder().encode(reversed); print(String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!)`, and see the output. It's the reverse, so it what should look like the JSON you received to be decoded with `decode([Post].self`. It's not the same, it's missing "meta" & "values“ as said...

Answer (score 1):

The error is speaking for itself; you are trying to decode an array but the JSON is a dictionary. You need to change your decode:

```
JSONDecoder().decode(Post.self, from: data)
```

**Edit** after Joakim Danielson hint for completeness of the answer:

You have also to modify your struct in order to accomodate the JSON in your response

```
struct Post: Decodable {
    let meta: Meta
}

struct Meta: Decodable {
    let symbol: String
    let interval: String
    let currency: String
    let values: [Values]
    // more data here
}

struct Values: Decodable {
    // more data here
}
```

Comment: already tried this a couple times but still doesnt get it working :/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **all** values in `Post` are `String`, please note the double quotes in the JSON

```
struct Post: Decodable {
    let datetime, open, high, low, close, volume: String
}
```

But the main issue is – as mentioned in the comments and Alastar's answer and indirectly stated by the error – you are ignoring the root object. You have to decode JSON always from the top. Add this struct

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let values: [Post]
}
```

and decode

```
let postsData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
completionHandler(postsData.values)
```